# Spring Mongo DocumentReference

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Switching to MongoDB from Postgres, the question arose of how best to organize the relationship between collections.

Does this annotation **@DocumentReference** support cascade delete and save...
Or is it necessary to first save the *ChildDocument* and then save the *ParentDocument*?

Answer (score 1):

You must save the child and then save the parent;

An example on the link: [here](https://spring.io/blog/2021/11/29/spring-data-mongodb-relation-modelling); look at title: Linking using Declarative Manual References

Comment: Why not vice versa? First the parent, then the children